# Coldfusion oracle jdbc Macromedia vs Thin

Tags: oracle, jdbc, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have done a lot of searching about this, but cannot seem to get a clear list of the limitations of Macromedia versus thin Oracle JDBC drivers, because they have big differences that I'm not understanding.

I have two data sources connected to the same database, using the same credentials in CF 9.0.1:

1. Thin

   - jdbc url = jdbc:oracle:thin
   - driver class = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
2. Macromedia

   - jdbc url = jdbc:macromedia:oracle
   - driver class = macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver

On an insert query

```
<cffunction name="create" access="public" output="false" >  
  <cfargument name="allocation_code" required="no"  type="string"/>           
  <cfquery datasource="#application.DSN#" name="qResult" result="r" >
     insert into table1 s
     (s.data)
     values (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.data#">
     )
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn r.ROWID>
</cffunction>
```

- The Thin datasource Fails (giving error ROWID does not exist)
- The Macromedia datasource is OK

---

On a  [dbinfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f-4439fdac128193edfd6-7f79.html) call

```
var columnList = new dbinfo( datasource="#application.DSN#"
                             , table="table1").columns();
```

- The Thin datasource is OK
- The Macromedia datasource never processes, eventually gives a cfoutput timeout error

---

On a stored procedure with an RC1 cursor

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="schema.myproc"  datasource="#application.DSN#" > 
    <cfprocparam  type = "IN"
        cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
        value="#Event.getValue("entityid")#"
        > 
    <cfprocresult name="RC1"> 
</cfstoredproc>
```

- The Thin datasource errors, wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'schema.myproc'
- The Macromedia datasource is OK

---

Is there a list of differences or pros/cons that I can reference? Or is this just a trial error I get to enjoy? Should I just have two different datasources and call them as needed when one doesn't work? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the Macromedia driver? Is this ColdFusion 9 Standard or Enterprise?

Comment: ColdFusion 9.01 still lists its drivers as Macromedia. Nothing special has to be done

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo i have standard local installed and was able to configure it, so both

Comment: If this is local, then your have Enterprise for 30 days, then it converts to Developer version. So you have the Oracle driver that ships with CF, but Standard in production doesn't have access to that driver IIRC. What version of CF will you have in production?

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo i will have Enterprise in production, developing using standard

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a list of differences or pros/cons that I can reference?* - I suspect you will need to read the documentation for each driver to get that information. See the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm) for the particular version of the thin datasource driver that you installed. ColdFusion ships with DataDirect for it's drivers. [ColdFusion 9.0.1 comes with DataDirect version 4.0 SP 1 drivers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSfd7453be0f56bba4bcf6a8f122a6749eaf-7fff.html).  See the [DataDirect docs for 4.0](http://www.datadirect.com/products/datadirect-connect/jdbc-drivers/features/connect-for-jdbc-release-notes-history/previous-release-4-0).

My thoughts on the specific examples that you gave.

> On an insert query
>
> - The Thin datasource Fails (giving error ROWID does not exist)
> - The Macromedia datasource is OK

Perhaps the thin datasource returns a different variable than `ROWID`. I would do a `<cfdump var="#r#">` after your `<cfquery>` call to see what you have available.

> On a dbinfo call
>
> - The Thin datasource is OK
> - The Macromedia datasource never processes, eventually gives a cfoutput timeout error

Not really sure what is happening here as you would expect that call to work. I would try a more generic (higher level) call to `dbinfo` and see what is available. Again, using `<cfdump>` to check returned values. Start with just `dbnames()` and see what you get. Then start digging into whatever is returned. This is really just informational for you and should not really affect your decision for production as you will not be using `dbinfo` there. Right?

> On a stored procedure with an RC1 cursor
>
> - The Thin datasource errors, wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'schema.myproc'
> - The Macromedia datasource is OK

The thin datasource driver does not support reference cursors in packages or stored procedures. It [says so in the ColdFusion docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f95.html).

> CFML supports Oracle 8 and 9 Reference Cursor type, which passes a parameter by reference. Parameters that are passed this way can be allocated and deallocated from memory within the execution of one application. To use reference cursors in packages or stored procedures, use the `cfprocresult` tag. This causes the ColdFusion JDBC database driver to put Oracle reference cursors into a result set. (**You cannot use this method with Oracle’s ThinClient JDBC drivers.**)

I would recommend using the DataDirect drivers that are shipped with ColdFusion. At least until they don't provide some sort of functionality that you need. Not until that point would I start looking at other alternatives. This will keep you within Adobe's support. Once you start using third-party software they cannot support them.

Comment: 1) i had dumped the thin source results, all standard , no identity values returned 2) agreed, but found strange that it only works with thin 3) I know rc1 cursors arent available via thin, was just using it in the context of listing differences and which would i choose

Comment: The datadirect drivers for oracle shipped with CF do not support oracle RAC clusters due to single node config,i ended up using macromedia jdbc

Comment: The macromedia jdbc drivers are datadirect?